# Elasticsearch issue

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4, elasticsearch

First of all, let me say i'm sure the code isn't responsible for this, because i have the same branch deployed on two different env, and the error just occurs in the second one. So, this as to be somehow a configuration or database error. But I can't see which one it is.

> [2021-02-18 15:21:06] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_2_v5","node":"ZRfeJsBKQwie8_mjHFqdTA","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}}},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_2_v5","node":"ZRfeJsBKQwie8_mjHFq","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [origin_pro] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}}},"status":400} at /home/preprod/www/releases/20210218145416/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:632)"}

The `origin_pro` attribute is something existing since a few month

```
$attributeCode = 'origin_pro';
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    $attributeCode,
    [
        'user_defined' => true,
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Origine Pro',
        'input' => 'text',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'default' => false,
        'searchable' => true,
        'filterable' => true,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
    ]
);
```

As a result this seems to cause my product list to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your origin_pro is a text value and can not be used as filterable that's why you are getting error on elasticsearch.
Solution : make that atrribute is_filterable = 0 from atrribute setting.

Comment: Well this is also what I made in the first place, but I wouldn't call it a solution (even if it's the one i'm using temporary), sure it will work but I won't be able to filter the attribute anymore after that. I'm sure there is some way to alterate elastic and being able to use text as filter.

Comment: Understand, if you find a solution please update your post please :)

Comment: Why don't you think to convert origin_pro attribute to select atrribute instead of text. What is the purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

Hello Just try below solution i got same error and it;s works fine with no issue: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027356612-Elasticsearch-5-is-configured-but-search-page-does-not-load-with-Fielddata-is-disabled-error